# Unsure of what program is currently not working in top bar

Tags: icons

So, I must've installed a program and uninstalled some of it's components, cause I have an icon in the top bar which is not working and I have **no** clue what it is.

I've tried manually closing applications in the "System monitor" program, but I have yet to find the one causing this icon.

Anyone have a suggestion to where I should start looking?

Thank you

[image: icon]

Comment: Are you using Dropbox? Also, are the usual system icons (Power, Notifications, Battery, Connection & Volume) all there and accounted for?

Comment: It only took 1 answer..
Yes I am using dropbox and yes.. that was the one!
Had no clue that Dropbox client was not working as the updates to/from this installation works fine.

THANK YOU!

Comment: Guessing Dropbox was the culprit? LOL

Answer (score 2):

It was Dropbox!
The backend-part of the application is working fine, but the client is apparently not functioning as intended.
Trying to re-install and thank you!